# How do I get a filter to open to the left and not the right?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am creating a mobile app using the Kendo Grid for MVC. When a user clicks on one of the column filters, a drop down menu appears. When you then click on the filter options, the window opens to the right and is not visible in the view port. You have to scroll to the right to select any options.

Is it possible to open the sub-menu to the left?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using adaptive rendering? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/adaptive

"To enable the adaptive rendering feature the developer should set mobile propery to true, phone or tablet."

If this does not solve your problem, please provide the code you're using for the grid.